# Spring Roo: How to edit tags' style

Tags: spring, twitter-bootstrap, jsp-tags, spring-roo, gvnix

I'm using gvNix to create an application. I enabled jQuery and Bootstrap, but I want to edit the colors and the layout of the pages.
For example, the create new user form looks like this
[image: Create User form]

However, you can see that the check boxes are not well positioned and the text fields and the button are very stretched.

I tried to edit the `create.jspx` tag but it is too complicated.

The list page is also not responsive.

[image: List All Users]

Comment: You need to modify the `*.tagx` files.

Comment: @Ralph I know that, but I don't know how to do that :)

Comment: i do not know that you mean by "I don't know how to do that" - I could answer "take some editor and modifiy the file" - but I do not think that his is the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to edit *checkbox* appearance you should edit `checkbox.tagx` file including the necessary **HTML** structure and **CSS** classes that you need in your project.

This file is located on `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/tags/jquery/form/fields`.

If you are thinking about to edit `tagx` files usually, you should read about [JSTL](https://jstl.java.net/)

On the other hand, **list** views generated by Spring Roo are not *responsive*. If you want to transform Spring Roo lists to responsive tables, you should use *gvNIX Datatables*. You could read more information about gvNIX Datatables [here](http://www.gvnix.org/assets/doc/gvnix-1.5.1.RC4-reference-docs.pdf).

The following link is an example about an application generated with gvNIX that includes responsive tables.

http://geo-gvnix.rhcloud.com (**user**: admin | **pass**: admin)

Hope this help·

Regards,